# MSVC warning C4305 double to float

Tags: c, visual-studio, floating-point

I have MSVC warning C4305: '-=' : truncation from 'double' to 'float'

```
float d;
d = (float)current_line->width/(float)fw;
if (d > 1.2) d -= 0.2;
```

How can I fix that?

Comment: `if (d > 1.2f) d -= 0.2f;`.

Comment: Thank you. Can you answer to my question?

Comment: This is a duplicate of approximately a bazillion questions. I'll be closed soon, I just thought you'd appreciate a quick hint.